# unicode in ggplot pdf output if Cairo is broken

Tags: r, ggplot2, pdf-generation, rstudio, cairo

I have been using `cairo_pdf(...)` to ggplot pdf's that contain unicode for phonetic (IPA) characters (like "\u025B"). This worked great until today when I updated RStudio to 1.1.456 and R to 3.5.1 (running on OS X 10.13.5). Now, when I call `cairo_pdf(...)` I get a message saying "failed to load cairo DLL".  I have done `install.packages("Cairo")`  and now library("Cairo") spits out a series of messages:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘Cairo’:
.onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'Cairo', details:
 error: unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/Cairo/libs/Cairo.so':
dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/Cairo/libs/Cairo.so, 6): Library not loaded: /opt/X11/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib
Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/Cairo/libs/Cairo.so
Reason: Incompatible library version: Cairo.so requires version 19.0.0 or later, but libfreetype.6.dylib provides version 17.0.0
```

I'm not sure whether I should try to work out what has changed in Cairo or R, or learn a different way to put unicode characters in plots. I did try .png outputs but the quality was inadequate.
tx

Comment: So this appears to be a question of "how to install an updated freetype library?" If you look at the DESCRIPTION file, you see: `SystemRequirements: cairo (>= 1.2 http://www.cairographics.org/)`

Comment: It could be - I had a hard time parsing the error messages, to be honest

Answer (score 0):

The most recent version of the system `cairo` package in the Mac `http://r.research.att.com/libs/` directory is: http://r.research.att.com/libs/cairo-1.14.2-darwin.13-x86_64.tar.gz

You might get some information and possibly even some success with the suggested method at the bottom the the libs page. Open Terminal.app and paste these two lines (all of them) into the Unix console:

```
curl -O http://r.research.att.com/libs/cairo-1.14.2-darwin.13-x86_64.tar.gz
sudo tar fvxz gmp-4.2.4-darwin8-bin4.tar.gz -C /
```

I edited your tags since the other possibility of a system issue is whether Rstudio honors or recognizes the location of the `cairo` lib.

On my Rstudio installation it seems to. I was able to load, update, run: `detach("package:Cairo", unload=TRUE)`, and reload the (R) Cairo package from the R console. But I'm not a particularly knowledgeable user of Rstudio. I'm still using the CRAN distributed R.app.

Comment: I'll try it; at this point I'm not sure even the tar worked:  sudo tar fvxz cairo-1.14.2-darwin.13-x86_64.tar.gz -C /
x usr/: Can't set user=0/group=0 for usrCan't update time for usr
x usr/local/: Can't set user=0/group=0 for usr/local
x usr/local/bin/  [....] but I'll study this shortly

Comment: I might be the wrong one for this question. Stuck at OSX 10.11.6 (15G21013) due to hardware. Perhaps the interim Apple security updates are preventing writing to certain system locations? I did notice that `../X11/..` was the location of one of the problem files so would try reinstalling the most recent version of XQuartz.

Comment: the research.att link seems to be 2015 software anyway, which makes me a bit suspicious that replacing whatever Cairo I've got with what's there would help; what I have in /usr/local/share is of that vintage. I did try loading the cairo library again within Rstudio and it failed in the same way.